# select an option from dropdown list when list is long

Tags: browser, robotframework, playwright

I am using `robot framework` [browser](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Select%20Options%20By) library to automate UI.

The UI has a dropdown list like this, a pretty long list.

[sample dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTjHM.png)

[short video how the HTML looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpP2A.gif)

sample HTML:

```
<div class="rc-virtual-list-holder-inner" style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;">
   <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Singapore Codeswitch 16k" style="">
      <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Singapore Codeswitch 16k</div>
      <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
   </div>
   <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="manualtest8020-v1-8k">
      <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">manualtest8020-v1-8k</div>
      <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
   </div>
   <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="mmlntu-v1-8k">
      <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">mmlntu-v1-8k</div>
      <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
   </div>
   <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="semicolon:test123-v1-8k">
      <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">semicolon:test123-v1-8k</div>
      <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
   </div>
   <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-active" title="train-again-v1-16k" style="">
      <div class="ant-select-item-option-content" style="">train-again-v1-16k</div>
      <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Test Case

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Upload New Dual Channel Audio
    Fill Text    ${TextField-Job-Name}     ${RandomNumber}
    click   //input[contains(@type,'search')]
    Select Options By     //div[contains(@class,'ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-active')]     text    Model-1-wav-stm-only-v1-8k
```

However error occured:

```
Error: locator.selectOption: Error: Element is not a <select> element
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//div[contains(@class,'ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-active')]"
  selector resolved to visible <div aria-selected="false" title="16000samplerate-60t…>…</div>
  selecting specified option(s)
  Element is not a <select> element
============================================================
```

Comment: It looks like keyword "Select Options By" expects a "select" element but your example is with a "div". From doc: "Selects options from select element found by selector" - It's not related to the length of the drop down

Comment: @MatthewKing  yes I figured out that I should use 'click' however, the value appear at very bottom, 'hover' or scroll to does not helps to click the value when it is appear at second part of list. any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure with Browser library - It might be trying to scroll the page rather than the list perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out by using `Hover` to the element then `Click` on it.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Upload New Dual Channel Audio
    Fill Text    ${TextField-Job-Name}     ${RandomNumber}
    click   //input[contains(@type,'search')]
    Hover    //div[@class='ant-select-item-option-content'][contains(.,'${value}')]
    Click   //div[@class='ant-select-item-option-content'][contains(.,'${value}')]
```